# org.apache.parquet.schema.InvalidSchemaException:Cannot write a schema with an empty group

Tags: api, azure-data-factory, parquet

I am extracting responses from an API in ADF, I used COPY activity source as REST API, and sink as ADLS Gen2 Parquet. When I debug the copy activity it fails for below reason.

[image]

Here is the response JSON(sample) that I get from API upon request.
Response JSON in the format of

```
{
    "Regions": [
        {
            "RCode": "a",
            "Name": "b",
            "DbCode": "c",
            "DisplayOrder": 1,
            "HasAccess": false
        },
        {
            "RCode": "e",
            "Name": "f",
            "DbCode": "g",
            "DisplayOrder": 2,
            "HasAccess": false
        },
}
```

But the WEB activity(without saving to ADLS) is completed successfully. Can Someone help me understand what the issue is?

Comment: Does writing the response to other file formats work in the copy data activity?

Comment: It is working when I used JSON as sink, and getting 0 Bytes when used a CSV as sink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the mapping setting manually in the copy activity. Otherwise, you will get that error.

- Got the same error when mapping is not given.

> ErrorCode=ParquetJavaInvocationException,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred when invoking java, message: org.apache.parquet.schema.InvalidSchemaException:Cannot write a schema with an empty group: message adms_schema

[image]

- In order to overcome this error, click the mapping tab in copy activity. Click `Import schemas`. Select `Advance editors` and click the `Region` array in collection reference and map the input column with output.

[image]

- When the pipeline is run, It is executed without any error.
- Similarly for delimited(csv) sink, when mapping is given, all records are copied. Otherwise, zero rows are copied to csv sink.

**Reference**: [Schema and data type mapping in copy activity - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping)